# DFT total energy from band energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, density-operator, density-functional-theory

I'm using Kohn-Sham DFT as a part of my research. The material is metallic crystal. In the following, you can assume that $\rho$ refers to the density matrix and $H$ refers to a hamiltonian matrix that have been expressed in an atomic orbital basis. I want to calculate the forces on the atoms. My Ph.D. supervisor has said that

> Once you verify that you can compute the correct total energy using $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho H)$ then the forces follow from this.

I don't understand that because

1. $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho H)$  seem to give me the sum of the Kohn-Sham eigenvalues multiplied by occupancy.
2. I have not seen a nice expression relating the eigenvalues to the total energy. But I was told that one has to «add on the simple analytical term for internuclear repulsion».

I could not quickly find anything on the Internet about this. I tried to calculate it using pyscf, but I still get the wrong answer.

It is such an important identity, so it would be helpful with an answer, stating the equation with all the appropriate definitions, and a reference to a page in text for the derivation of the mathematical identity (unless you like to show it).

If something is not clear, please let me know in the comments, and I will add details as you required.

Comment: Consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE. They have many experts on DFT/ practical DFT calculations.

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0211443.pdf) after eq. 73... does that help? See also the last equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn%E2%80%93Sham_equations).

Comment: DFT is a highly studied system and you should be looking for textbooks covering that topic rather than "on the internet". However, what your advisor is talking about the forces should be the obvious relation coming from the derivative of the Hamiltonian eigenvalue for the ground state. Or Feynman-Hellmann theorem. pyscf implements them and gives them to you. You really should properly learn about the tools you are using.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Looks like the op is trying to determine the total energy from the band energy (something akin to Tobias Fünke comment). The op isn't asking about Feynman-Hellmann (as far as I can tell). Why are you lecturing about what to learn at which time?